# mongoDB replication to ATLAS

Tags: mongodb

Is there such possibility to have one of my replicaSet members in ATLAS and the others to be in my local machine? ( Kind of backup in ATLAS in case something go wrong with my local setup )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  Atlas is a fully managed service. Having Altas manage some members of a replica set while you manage the others sounds like recipe for misconfiguration, miscommunication, and down time.

You could certainly have one replica set member in the cloud provider instance with the rest local.